# Jquery fade background on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

There is a link, with no background, and a css rule, which changes background on hover.

Parent bg is white, link on hover - blue.

**How can I do a hover effect slowly**, from white to blue?

Thanks.

```
li a {}
li a:hover { background: blue; }
```

Answer (score 11):

```
jQuery('a#theLink').hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor: 'blue'});
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor: 'white'});
});
```

For this to work you need to download the "**[color plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color)**" for jQuery.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need an extra color plugin. You just need jQuery UI on top of jQuery, which lets you do animations also on color. (Or if you don't want to use jQuery UI for some reason, I guess another plugin will do the trick. But I have successfully tried this with just including jQuery core and jQuery UI.)

Animation itself goes something like...

```
$("li").hover(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff"
  }, 'slow');
});
```

Comment: I know file sizes aren't too much of an issue these days at the level of kilobytes (although stuff does add up), but just for the record: jquery.color.js - 4k | jquery-ui-1.8rc3.custom.min.js - 64k

Comment: Stating the obvious, since no one else has, if you are already using jQuery UI you are good to go. If you are not using jQuery UI then don't start using it just for this feature -- use the color plugin.

Comment: maybe this was true when posted, but as of now... "For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used" http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 2):

bgFade a very great and simple plugin that animates de background image:

http://www.isthatclear.com/jquery/bgFade/

Answer (score 1):

In order to animate colors, you need the [color plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a plugin as JQuery can't animate colours out of the box.

Try the [Colour Animation plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color)

Then it'll be something like:

```
$(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "blue" }, 'slow');
```

Comment: Those links don't go anywhere, just he jQuery website. Same as in James's answer.

Comment: The answer is almost 5 years old so the link must have moved, however, you can now animate colors using JQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/animate/