# jquery button fade with background image acting strange

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a button fade into another class by using the toggleClass method. This seems to work fine until I introduce a background image into the classes.

I'm not even sure what it is doing exactly.. It seems to depend on where the mouse is on the button. Anyways the button sort of starts the fade, possibly where it is just the background color not image, and then just "pops" in the background once it completes the animation. I recreated it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/2YbqH/1/

So my question is.. how can i make the whole thing fade?

Comment: I think this is similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808790/jquery-fade-background-on-hover - you are trying to fade a background

Comment: It's considered good form (and will get you high quality answers) to provide the code inside the question as well, not just externally in a fiddle. Formatting for readability is also welcome in both places (ie. not just long single-line blocks of CSS)

Comment: Sorry didn't know that about posting code in here as well.. I thought one or the other. I will edit the question. I will also remove the unnecessary css.

Comment: JMax has it right. Here's a fiddle with background color only (and that's all that has changed) and the transition works: http://jsfiddle.net/2YbqH/2/ They mention a plugin in the bottom of the answer he links to, but I can't vouch for it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really fade between classes. An element either has a class, or it doesn't.

Comment: I don't think it'd be that hard to write. It just isn't how it works right now, and I don't think it is how it should work either.

Comment: I am actually using jquery UI already so I tried toggleClass as well and it's the same result.

Comment: Yup, I misread your original question; I've deleted my previous comments since they didn't make sense in that context. toggleClass actually SHOULD (according to docs) do this, but when you're transitioning this many styles, many of them with vendor prefixes, I'm not surprised that it's failing.

Comment: yeah, I think I see the issue. Added another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to toggle the class, just toggle the attributes of that class. Assuming you aren't doing too many crazy things, it should be rather simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate color values without the [color plugin](http://bit.ly/yyWZYV)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can't fade into classes, but **it is POSSIBLE** with a trick

```
$('button').on("mouseenter",function(){
     $(this).fadeOut(100).toggleClass("ui-state-hover").fadeIn(100);
});
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2YbqH/3/). Basically, the idea is to fade out, then toggle the class and show again.

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/2YbqH/6/) demo to fake a background, when the button are fading out and in. I hope you will be do what you want from these demos.

Comment: that kinda sorta works.. but not good enough.. It has to fadeout completely before starting the fade in so it makes it look like it is "flashing" off for a split second.

Comment: Wow, not good enough. You are sounding my boss. I am not working for you Sir. But I am cool, You can always add a background image to fake it. I will create a fiddle to show you.

Comment: @Sackling, check the update, and you can remove that `100` and replace with `0` from my code above, if you dont want the flashing to go and directly come.